# Does java ConcurrentLinkedQueue have constant time performance for remove?

Tags: concurrency, queue

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

I know this data structure has constant time performance for enqueue and dequeue, but does it have constant time performance for remove(Object o)?

Comment: I guess I'd feel fairly safe in saying *no* after a little reading. The class docs state that it is based on a series of linked nodes. Enqueue and dequeue are constant time due to adding to known nodes, but removing from an arbitrary location would *likely* have about the same runtime as removal from a linked list: linear time. Interestingly, size() is also not a constant time operation... All this being said, I'd like somebody else to chime in here too - this is based on my interpretation of the docs.

Comment: @JTrana You are right. Here is the the openjdk implementation - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java#ConcurrentLinkedQueue.remove%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 2):

I think looking at [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java#ConcurrentLinkedQueue.remove%28java.lang.Object%29)of ConcurrentLinkedQueue can give clear answer.

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    Node<E> pred = null;
    for (Node<E> p = first(); p != null; p = succ(p)) {
        E item = p.item;
        if (item != null &&
            o.equals(item) &&
            p.casItem(item, null)) {
            Node<E> next = succ(p);
            if (pred != null && next != null)
                pred.casNext(p, next);
            return true;
        }
        pred = p;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, there is iteration through queue nodes with checking each node before removing node is found. With this we can say removing performance is linearly dependent on queue size. So in compare with enqueue and dequeue, **ConcurrentLinkedQueue remove(Object) method has not constant time performance**, but is dependent on queue size.